# Добавление комментариев из соцсетей

Tags: php, соцсети

Добрый день! Подскажите как реализовать такую штуку, как показано на картинке?
[image]

Интересует подключение таких комментариев для FaceBook и для Вконтакте.
Это первый вопрос. И второй вопрос, как реализовать вкладки, при помощи которых можно
открывать комментарии каждой соцсети, как показано на рисунке? Буду благодарен за исчерпывающие ответы, так как с этими фичами ни разу не работал.

Comment: Для контакта вот тут https://vk.com/dev/Comments  
Для фейсбука предполагаю что-то аналогичное есть.  
Вкладки делаются через js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Комментирования это обычные виджеты от vk и facebook. Как их установить найдете на dev разделах:

1. https://vk.com/dev/Comments
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Вкладки это небольшая хитрость верстки, где заголовки вкладок - ссылки, а активная область нужной вкладки обычный div, который меняет свое состоянии (show/hide) при клике на определенную вкладку. Div-ы в свою очередь содержат нужный виджет. Как-то так:

```
<div id="tab-wrapper">
    <a class="tab" data-content="tab1" href="#">Вкладка 1</a>
    <a class="tab" data-content="tab2" href="#">Вкладка 2</a>
</div>
<div id="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="data-content">Контент вкладки 1</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="data-content">Контент вкладки 2</div>
</div>
```

Осталось javascript прикрутить, чтобы это работало

UPD: можно использовать готовый вариант вкладок от bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

Интеграция комментирования в соц.сетях реализовано через виджеты. Для вконтакте: https://vk.com/dev/Comments, и для facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments
Вкладки можно сделать с помощью jquery tabs: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Войди в раздел "разработчикам" на главной странице VK. Потом выбери виджеты... Настраивай и вставляй код себе на страничку! С Фэйсом примерно также)